# awk (or sed/grep) to get occurrences of substring

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a json string in a bash variable, which is something like this:

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703000,
        "bar": 123
      },
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703200,
        "bar": 456
      },
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703400,
        "bar": 789
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to know how many of those `timestamp`s are after a given datetime, so if I have `1553703100` it'll return `2`.

(Bonus imaginary points if you can get me just that number!)

As a step towards that, I want to get just the matches of `"timestamp": \d+,` in the string so that I can loop through them in a bash script.

I've used sed and grep a bit, but never used awk, and from my reading it seems like that might be the better match for the task.

Other info:
- The json is already pretty-printed, as above, so the timestamps would always be on separate lines.
- This is to run in Cygwin, so I have awk/gawk, sed, and grep/egrep, but probably not others.
- Could be any number of timestamps in the json.

Comment: Use 'jq' to parse JSON

Comment: @GillesQuenot, OP specified the available tools

Comment: `jq` is available on cygwin.

Comment: I don't know how to use `jq` because everyone's so busy telling me to use it that they forget to post actual solutions with it.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Both answers are excellent. Turns out I don't have `jq` installed, so I'll use the awk solution. Wish I could mark 2 answers as accepted :-(

Comment: Hi @Redzarf, thanks for the accept. Please see my update for important changes necessary for production code.

Comment: I have also added a python solution ;-) Hope it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*edit: The second approach listed below has serious problems that were very helpfully outlined by @EdMorton. I've elected to keep the old code for educational purposes.*

Avoided `substr()` and caught null string `i`:

```
$ awk -v dt=1553703100 '
  /timestamp/ && $2+0>dt {i++}
  END {print i+0}
' <<< "$var"

2
```

---

**WARNING: PROBLEMATIC CODE**

Here I used `substr(string, index, [characters])` to trim the comma off your second field. The `/timestamp/` regex is not complex; it could be improved if your json became more intricate.

```
$ awk -v dt=1553703100 '
  /timestamp/ && substr($2, 0, length($2)) > dt {i++} 
  END {print i}
' <<< "$var"

2
```

Comment: The 2nd arg for substr() is the starting position of the substring. All array indices, fields, and strings in awk start at 1, not 0. When you use `0` as the 2nd arg to substr() awk treats it like it would any other invalid value (try `awk 'BEGIN{print substr("bananas",-27,3)}'`) and treats it as if you had specified `1` instead. The 3rd arg is how long you want the substr to be. Using `length($2)` is the same as leaving that field empty as it'll give you the full length of the string. ITYM `substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)` but you could instead just use `$2+0` to strip the `,`.

Comment: The final print should be `print i+0` so you get a numeric output even if no values match (as opposed to a null string output in that case).

Answer (score 4):

You didn't provide the expected output so it's a  guess but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ echo "$var" | jq '.items[].timestamp'
1553703000
1553703200
1553703400
```

or maybe:

```
$ echo "$var" | jq '.items[].timestamp | select(. > 1553703100)'
1553703200
1553703400
```

or:

```
$ echo "$var" | jq '[.items[].timestamp | select(. > 1553703100)] | length'
2
```

WARNING: I'm just learning `jq` so there may be better ways to do the above!

Comment: Neat, thanks. OP specified he wants a count of records greater than a specified timestamp. Any way to do that in `jq`?

Comment: @vintnes I googled a few `jq` examples and updated my answer based on  them.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement quickly a `python` solution:

**input**:

```
$ cat data.json 
{
    "items": [
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703000,
        "bar": 123
      },
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703200,
        "bar": 456
      },
      {
        "foo": null,
        "timestamp": 1553703400,
        "bar": 789
      }
    ]
}
```

**code**:

```
$ cat extract_value2.py 
import json

tLimit = 1553703100
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print([t['timestamp'] for t in data["items"] if t['timestamp'] > tLimit])
```

**output**:

```
$ python extract_value2.py 
[1553703200, 1553703400]
```

**count code:**

```
$ cat extract_value2.py 
import json

tLimit = 1553703100
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    print(len([t['timestamp'] for t in data["items"] if t['timestamp'] > tLimit]))
```

**output**:

```
$ python extract_value2.py
2
```